# How do I find the dependencies for a program before trying to compile it?

Tags: dependencies, compiler

I was trying to cross-compile a program for ARM.
While compiling I was very much irritated as I had to look for a number of dependencies e.g `fatal error: abc/xyz.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated`.

After ensuring that compiler gets the missing files, when I recompiled, I got same error for about 30 files.

I have no idea if that is normal behaviour.

If it is normal, is there a method which can help the compiler find the dependencies on its own?

If that is not normal, then please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If your computer has enough processing core you can try to speed up the compilation using `-j` option. Apart from this advice, I have no idea about the problem your are facing.  (Check this for `-j` options http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/ch05s04.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the -M flag in gcc?  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: thats exactly what i am looking for.
Thanks @Sam